# What are the origins of St. Joseph's title "Guardian of Virgins"?

Tags: catholicism, origin, joseph-husband-of-mary, devotion

When and where did St. Joseph's title "Guardian of Virgins" originate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It comes from the [Litany of St. Joseph](https://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Ioseph/LitStIoeseph.html): *Custos virginum*.

Comment: The Litany of Saint Joseph was approved for public use by Pope Pius X in 1909. The origin of this invocation most certainly predates this time frame.

Comment: @KenGraham Yes, the litany existed before 1909.

Comment: Like the Litanies of Loreto, the litanies were simply added to by various individuals and popes. My guess is that no one knows. It is simply a compilation over time. Even in modern times, the various litanies approved by the Church are being added to. The question is about the title, ***Guardian of Virgins*** and not the Litany of St. Joseph! In fact it was not until 1726 that Pope Benedict XIII, actually inserted the name of St. Joseph into the Litany of the Saints. See [here](https://www.sistersofcarmel.com/devotion-to-st-joseph/).

Answer (score 1):

**What are the origins of St. Joseph's title *“Guardian of Virgins”*?**

In 1909, Pope St. Pius X approved [**The Litany of St. Joseph**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Litany_of_Saint_Joseph) for public use, but the origins of the title **Guardian of Virgins** (*Custos virginum*) is much older.

Devotion towards St. Joseph slowly developed over the centuries, but in the 17th century, it started to blossom.

The origins of this title certainly dates back to the 1600s.

> [**The Miraculous History of the Cord**](https://www.catholiccompany.com/magazine/the-white-cord-of-st-joseph-what-you-should-know-about-this-unique-devotional-6214)
>
> This beautiful devotion began almost 400 years ago in the small town of Antwerp, Belgium. An Augustinian nun named Sr. Elizabeth was suffering from a mysterious and painful illness; doctors admitted that it would most likely lead to her death. Having a special devotion to St. Joseph, she asked that a cord be blessed in his honor. She wrapped this cord around her waist. A few days later, her pain disappeared while she was praying for St. Joseph’s intercession. Multiple doctors—including a Protestant doctor—accessed her case and proclaimed her cure to be miraculous.
>
> Almost 200 years later, the miracle was publicized—particularly in Verona, Italy—and in March of 1842, this devotional cord was adopted by a hospital in Verona and distributed to its patients. On September 19, 1859, the devotion of St. Joseph’s cord was officially adopted; a blessing formula created; indulgences added by Pope Pius IX; and widespread private use permitted.
>
> The White Cord of St Joseph is piously used not only as a remedy against physical ailments, but as a support in living the virtues of chastity and purity of heart.
>
> **Graces Associated with the Cord**
>
> There are five primary graces attached to the wearing of the cord and the pious recitation of the corresponding prayers:
>
> 1. St. Joseph's special protection
> 2. Purity of soul
> 3. The grace of chastity
> 4. Final perseverance
> 5. Particular assistance at the hour of death
>
> The following is recommended for this devotional:
>
> The Cord of St. Joseph should be of thread or cotton, ending at one extremity in seven knots, indicative of the Seven Joys and Sorrows of St. Joseph. It is worn as a girdle for purity or chastity and humility, and around the shoulders for obedience. It ought to be blessed by a priest with the faculties for this blessing. Pius IX approved a special formula for the blessing of the cord of St. Joseph.
> The daily commitments associated with the devotion are to pray seven Glory Be's along with a prayer to St. Joseph for Purity:
>
> O **Guardian of Virgins** and holy Father St. Joseph, into whose faithful keeping were entrusted
> Christ Jesus, Innocence Itself, and Mary, Virgin of virgins, I pray and beseech thee by these dear pledges, Jesus and Mary, that, being preserved from all uncleanness, I may with spotless mind, pure heart and chaste body, ever serve Jesus and Mary most chastely all the days of my life. Amen.

The title and origins of **Guardian of Virgins** goes back a least to [Father Jean-Jacques Olier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Jacques_Olier), S.S., (20 September 1608 – 2 April 1657):

> [**Invocations to St. Joseph**](https://sensusfidelium.us/prayers-devotions-to-st-joseph/)
>
> *By Father Olier*
>
> Hail Joseph, image of God the Father.
>
> Hail Joseph, father of God the Son.
>
> Hail Joseph, temple of the Holy Ghost.
>
> Hail Joseph, beloved of the Holy Trinity.
>
> Hail Joseph, most faithful helper in the great plan of Redemption.
>
> Hail Joseph, most worthy spouse of the Virgin Mother.
>
> Hail Joseph, father of all the faithful.
>
> Hail Joseph, **guardian of holy virgins**.
>
> Hail Joseph, greatest lover of poverty.
>
> Hail Joseph, example of meekness and patience.
>
> Hail Joseph, mirror of humility and obedience.
>
> Blessed art thou among all men.
>
> And blessed are thine eyes, which have seen what thou hast seen.
>
> And blessed are thine ears, which have hears what thou hast heard.
>
> And blessed are thy hands, which have touched the Word Incarnate.
>
> And blessed are thine arms, which have carried the One Who carries all things.
>
> And blessed is thy breast, on which the Son of God most sweetly reposed.
>
> And blessed is thy heart, kindled with most ardent love.
>
> And blessed be the Eternal Father, Who chose thee.
>
> And blessed be the Son, Who loved thee.
>
> And blessed be the Holy Ghost, Who sanctified thee.
>
> And blessed be Mary, thy spouse, who loved thee as a spouse and a brother.
>
> And blessed be the Angel who guarded thee.
>
> And blessed be forever all who bless thee and who love thee.

[image: St. Joseph]

[St. Joseph](https://www.catholiccompany.com/magazine/the-white-cord-of-st-joseph-what-you-should-know-about-this-unique-devotional-6214)

Comment: Do you know who composed the Litany of St. Joseph in the first place? Have any saints commentated on it (like St. Alphonsus Liguori did for the Litany of Loreto in his "[Meditations on the Litany of Loreto](https://books.google.com/books?id=tWcXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA611#v=onepage&q&f=false)")?

Comment: Like the Litanies of Loreto, the litanies were simply added to by various individuals and popes. My guess is that no one knows. It is simply a compilation over time. Even in modern times, the various litanies approved by the Church are being added to. The question is about the title, ***Guardian of Virgins*** and not the Litany of St. Joseph!

Comment: Here is [a commentary on the titles of St. Joseph](https://books.google.com/books?id=sytV8WJFHC8C&pg=PA418), similar to [St. Alphonsus's on Our Lady](https://books.google.com/books?id=tWcXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA611).